# Publish on wall (status, link, video etc) with security

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, iphone-sdk-3.0, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using facebook-ios-sdk. I want to publish on FaceBook wall with security (status, link, video, whatever else), so that only specific friends can see the update.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the privacy arguments in this link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

and code is like this. **this code is just for status update**

```
NSDictionary *privacyDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"SELF",@"value",
                   nil];
SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
NSString *privacyJSONStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:privacyDict];
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"my message", @"message",
                   privacyJSONStr, @"privacy",
                   nil];
```

Set the objectofkey **(value,friends,networks,allow,deny)** of dictionary privacyDict according to your use

```
NSDictionary *privacyDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"CUSTOM",@"value",
                   @"SOME_FRIENDS",@"friends",
                   @"[comma separated friends id]",@"allow",
                   nil];
```